# detect whether [] operator of vector was used in RHS or LHS

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose the following is the [] operator implementation for vector:

```
template<class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](unsigned int index)
{
    if(index >= my_capacity) {
        if(1 /*something to check that [] operator was used in RHS (means read)*/) cout << "Out of bounds read" << endl;
        else cout << "Out of bounds write" << endl; //means write operation
    }
    return arr[index];
}
```

And now inside main():

```
Vector<int> v(5, 10); //initializes 5 values, each = 10
```

Now, let's say I have 2 statements

```
int ans = v[10]; //First
v[10] = 1; //Second
```

I basically want to get the output as:

```
Out of bounds read
Out of bounds write
```

How should I decide the condition inside the 'if' for the same (that whether the call to [] operator is a read or a write one)? Can anyone please help me in this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think you can differentiate between First and Second without additional information to the call.

Comment: @RSahu I also feel the same but what additional parameter can I send?

Comment: Are you doing it just for the nice logging?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry I didn't understand

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

The workaround is to return not a reference, but instead a proxy object that can detect whether it's read from or written to. But because C++ doesn't (yet) allow overloading `operator .`, such proxies can never be fully transparent.

My experience says that it's not worth it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do what you want is to have `operator[]` return a proxy object that implements separate conversion (read) and assignment (write) operators, eg:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct VectorProxy
{
    Vector<T> &vec;
    unsigned int index;

    operator T&() {
        if (index >= vec.my_capacity) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Out of bounds read");
        return vec.arr[index];
    }

    VectorProxy& operator=(const T &val) {
        if (index >= vec.my_capacity) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Out of bounds write");
        vec.arr[index] = val;
        return *this;
    }
};

template<class T>
VectorProxy Vector<T>::operator[](unsigned int index)
{
    return VectorProxy{*this, index};
}

/* optionally:

template<class T>
struct VectorConstProxy
{
    const Vector<T> &vec;
    const unsigned int index;

    operator const T&() const {
        if (index >= vec.my_capacity) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Out of bounds read");
        return vec.arr[index];
    }
};

template<class T>
VectorConstProxy Vector<T>::operator[](unsigned int index) const
{
    return VectorConstProxy{*this, index};
}
*/
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    ...
    Vector<int> v(5, 10);

    try {
        int ans = v[10];
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    try {
        v[10] = 1;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    ...
}
```

Obviously, `Vector(Const)Proxy` will have to be declared as a `friend` of `Vector` if `arr` and `my_capacity` are not `public`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

1. Define couple of helper `struct`s -- one to use for reading from and the other to write to.
2. Overload `operator[]` with those types.
3. Update the calls to use the appropriate helper objects.

```
struct ReadIndex { unsigned int index = 0;};
struct WriteIndex { unsigned int index = 0;};

template<class T>
T const& Vector<T>::operator[](ReadIndex r) const
{
    if(r.index >= my_capacity) {
        cout << "Out of bounds for read" << endl;
    }
    return arr[r.index];
}

template<class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](WriteIndex w)
{
    if(w.index >= my_capacity) {
        cout << "Out of bounds for write" << endl;
    }
    return arr[w.index];
}
```

Usage:

```
int ans = v[ReadIndex{10}];
v[WriteIndex{10}] = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, how about just using 2 methods named `GetRead` and `GetWrite`? That's a simpler approach if you have free rein over how the class is used.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, it might be a personal taste but I like overloading based on types instead of having differently named functions.